# Baby level python: Classes, and using them

Tags: python

I am learning about classes and seem to be having a hard time grasping it. In an attempt to get some practice, I have written the following code:

```
class Customer:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def newAge(self):
    self.age = self.age + 1

  def __str__(self):
    return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.name, self.age)
```

I want to print the customers age, and their new age. So I have got:

```
p1 = Customer("Amelia",21)
print (p1)

new = p1.newAge()
print (new)
```

The problem here is that the `new` variable is not storing anything, so it prints `None`. Can anyone tell me why my variable is storing none? I know that I have called the `newAge` incorrectly, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Methods without a `return` statement return `None` by default. Make `newAge()` return `self.age`.

Comment: It's not that you're wrong.  I feel like you're overlooking the actual misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

While the advice in other questions is correct - that is, you have to have a `return` method with a meaningful value, or you'll always return `None` - you don't *need* to store that value outside of the class instance.  It's a value that's updated internally, and you have other means of getting to it.

Think of it like this: a customer comes in and decides that today is their birthday, so they add one to their age.  This is effectively what the `newAge` method is accomplishing; it's adding 1 to the internal `self.age` variable.

You have only exposed their actual age when you ask them to identify themselves, in which they'll tell you their name *and* age.  That's what the `__str__` method is accomplishing; it tells you that particular customer's name and age in one fell swoop.

Thus, you can omit the assignment entirely and the code will behave as you expect if you print `p1` instead of `new`.

As an aside - if you wanted to add some sort of getter, you *could* (with an appropriate name)...

```
def getAge(self):
    return self.age
```

...or you could access the property directly, which is more conventional from what I've experienced.

```
p1 = Person('Steve?', 27)
print(p1.age)  # prints 27
```

Answer (score 0):

newAge does not return a value, therefore `new = p1.newAge()` returns `None`. If you `return self.age` at the end of that method, it will do what I think you want it to.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem without a return statement?